# Laravel Undefined index: document using PHPWord and DomPDF

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf, phpword

I'm trying to convert a odt file to a pdf, using PHPWord and DomPDF, I've read some issue on their git about how to do it and found this one [guide](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/311). But I'm getting and error on laravel about the PHPWord library Undefined index: document on the route

> C:\xampp\htdocs\DAW2M14\vendor\phpoffice\phpword\src\PhpWord\Reader\Word2007.php

```
foreach ($steps as $step) {
    $stepPart = $step['stepPart'];
    $stepItems = $step['stepItems'];
    foreach ($relationships[$stepPart] as $relItem) {
        $relType = $relItem['type'];
        if (isset($stepItems[$relType])) {
            $partName = $stepItems[$relType];
            $xmlFile = $relItem['target'];
            $this->readPart($phpWord, $relationships, $partName, $docFile, $xmlFile);
        }
    }
}
```

The error starts in the foreach.

My PHP code is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\URL_Document;
use App\Document;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

class CU_13Controller extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function generaPDF(Request $request, $id, $nombre, $path, $pathb, $formato) {

        $ruta=$path.'/'.$pathb;

        if($formato == "pdf"){
            return response()->download(storage_path("app/{$ruta}"));
        }else{
            $FilePath = "app/".$ruta;

            $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
            $document = $phpWord->loadTemplate(storage_path("app/{$ruta}"));
            $document->saveAs('temp.odt');

            $domPdfPath = base_path('/../vendor/dompdf/dompdf');
            \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererPath($domPdfPath);
            \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererName('DomPDF');

            $phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load('temp.odt');
            $pdfWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter( $phpWord, 'PDF' );
            $pdfWriter->save(storage_path("app/documents{$nombre}.pdf"));

            return response()->download(storage_path("app/documents{$nombre}.pdf"));
        }

    }
}
```

I don't know what kind of error I am doing

Comment: Please share the exact error

Comment: Image of the error in this [link](https://i.gyazo.com/ccf910e49d36b57716c49fd780dbaa5d.png)

Comment: Are there spaces in the file name? Any spaces or illegal filename characters would have to be escaped. Illegal filenames are not the same cross-platform.

Comment: @JeffHarris The file path and the name path it's: app/documents/G22MSDiZE7ALTTYPseKN1CmlR6E3eNJtcptLXTU3.odt

Comment: @Eguti Can't really tell from your error link, but make sure your `$domPdfPath` is pointing to the correct directory.